# receive gps location update in background mode ??iOS 8

Tags: ios, background, core-location

i have used the following code when the app enters background but the location is not getting updated

```
if(noTripRunning && somethingLeftToSync){
    NSLog(@"Bg task started.");
    self.bgTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:self.bgTask];
        self.bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
        DebugLog(@"Background task complete.");
    }];
}
else if(self.bgTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid){
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:self.bgTask];
    self.bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    DebugLog(@"Ended background task.");
}
```

Comment: None of the code shown is anything to do with location.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should include some more information about your situation, for example the location code of the core location manager.
iOS 8 adds some new steps in order for the app to be able to start the process of asking for location updates.
If these steps are are not implemented correctly, the code will fail silently and you won't be notified why.
more on this matter you should check out this [link](http://nevan.net/2014/09/core-location-manager-changes-in-ios-8/).

Now to your question, I can't really give you a direct answer since you haven't provided enough information.
But in any case, here [is a very good example](https://github.com/voyage11/Location) of how to work with updating the app's location in the background and keeping it from terminating.
I would suggest to download the zip file and test it your self.